# Application work in processes without startup - WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF application which has a daily restart timer, after daily restarting the application doesn't open, it is only appear in processes (taskbar for Win7) but not applications bar.
There is no logged exception, also I logged a string in the beginning of startup function but also not logged.

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Kiosk.Controls"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Wpf.Controls.Converters;assembly=Wpf.Controls"
    x:Class="Kiosk.App"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Resources scoped at the Application level should be defined here. -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:InverBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InverBooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
            <converters:IntToVisibilityConverter x:Key="IntToVisibilityConverter"/>
            <converters:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter"/>
            <controls:FlowDocumenConverter x:Key="FlowDocumenConverter"/>
            <controls:NullToImageConverter x:Key="NullToImageConverter" />
            <FontFamily x:Key="DuBoldFont">pack://application:,,,/Font/#du Co Headline 16 iOS</FontFamily>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/001DefaultStyle.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/002Decorations.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/003Buttons.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/004LanguageButton.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/005ScrollViwer.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/006Window.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/007Pager.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/008ListView.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/009ProgressBar.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/010EnterLabel.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/011TextBlock.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/012FlowDocument.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/013EnterStringView.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/014MakeRequestStyle.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/015InvoiceEnterMoney.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/016ImageButton.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/017Browser.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/018Logo.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/019TitleLogo.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/020TransactionInformation.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/021Keyboards.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/022EnterPhoneView.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/023ConfirmInvoiceView.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/024IndoorInfoEntry.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/025CertifyInvoiceView.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/026ConfirmInputData.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Default/027ShowBarCodeView.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: How is the restart done?

Comment: By using ExitWindowsEx 
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ExitWindowsEx.html